# Extended real numbers ordering of infinity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Consider the extended real numbers, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Show that for any $A\subseteq B\subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we have

$infB\leq infA$

My attempt:

The first case: Suppose $B=\varnothing$ then $infB=\infty$
and $infA=\infty$.

But, how can I then conclude that $infB\leq infA$? This doesn't make alot of sense. Is there a particular convention im not aware of?

Comment: Maybe the newbie belief that $\leq$ is not reflexive. Namely, that $a\leq a$ is not true. You do have $\infty\leq\infty$. By the way, when $A=\emptyset$ you define $\inf(A)=-\infty$, rather than $+\infty$. You also have $-\infty\leq-\infty$. You can type $\inf$ with the command `\inf`.

Comment: To finish the proof you can assume that $\inf(A)<\inf(B)$. This means that $\inf(B)\neq-\infty$ and in particular $B\neq\emptyset$. Now, let $x$ be $\frac{\inf(A)+\inf(B)}{2}$, if $\inf(A)\neq-\infty$ or equal to $\inf(B)-1$, if $\inf(A)=-\infty$. Then, by definition of $\inf(B)$ all elements $y\in B$ satisfy $x<y$. By definition of $\inf(A)$ and since $\inf(A)<x$ there must be at least one element $z\in A$ such that $z<x$. Then $z\in A$, but since $z<x$ and all elements of $B$ are larger than $x$ we got a $z$ that is in $A\setminus B$. This contradicts $A\subset B$.

Comment: $\infty\le\infty$ is true, just like $30\le30$ is. What's the problem?

Comment: @Gae.S. i thought that inequality is undefined, am I mistaken?

Comment: In $\overline{\Bbb R}=[-\infty,\infty]$, yes, you are.

Comment: @flan in fact, *all* reals are a lower bound for $\emptyset$ so the largest one ( the inf) is $+\infty$, not $-\infty$! This is completely standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline{  \Bbb R}$ is a partial order, so for all its elements $x$ we have $x \le x$, in particular for $x=\infty$. No problem.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.